# Setting frame on subview disables interaction

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a long press Gesture recogniser for different cells.

I have a subview with two buttons on it.

The subview can be interacted with if my code is this

```
- (IBAction)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {


if (sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    return;
}

    NSArray * views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RoomEditIconOverlay" owner:self options:nil];
    UIViewController * editViewController = [views objectAtIndex:0];

    [self.view addSubview:editViewController.view];
    [editViewController.view becomeFirstResponder];//Required
}
```

However if i set the frame at any point then i just interact with the parental view.

```
- (IBAction)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {


if (sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    return;
}

    NSArray * views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RoomEditIconOverlay" owner:self options:nil];
    UIViewController * editViewController = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    [editViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height -500, self.view.frame.size.width ,168)];

    [self.view addSubview:editViewController.view];
    [editViewController.view becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I can have it at the wrong position (with no animations either) and be able to interact. Or have it in the correct position with no interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by me setting the frame with not enough height.